# Lazy loading SwiftUI grid sheet both vertically and horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gridview, lazyvstack

I tried to build a grid view that loads lazily on both vertical and horizontal axes, the main goal is building a calendar for a list of employees. Both the list and the calendar interval can be very large so they have to be rendered lazily. I've tried `LazyHGrid` and `LazyVGrid` but they only render views lazily on one direction. The further approach uses one `LazyVStack` for the whole view and one `LazyHStack` for each row, the loading is lazy (check print in the console) but while scrolling the views, it loses their position and the grid gets broken. I also need fixed headers, that is achieved in the code using `pinnedViews`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 20, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                Section(header: columnHeaders) {
                    ForEach(0..<20) { row in
                        LazyHStack(spacing: 20, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                            Section(header: rowHeader(with: "Employee \(row)")) {
                                ForEach(0..<100) { column in
                                    Text("Cell \(row), \(column)")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                                        .background(Color.red)
                                        .onAppear {
                                            print("Cell \(row), \(column)")
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var columnHeaders: some View {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 20, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
            Section(header: rowHeader(with: "")) {
                ForEach(0..<100) { column in
                    Text("Header \(column)")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .background(Color.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func rowHeader(with label: String) -> some View {
        Text(label)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

[Lazy Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLboh.gif)

Tried what was said above.